# Sprite Health in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a very basic game, and I'm trying to make it so that the bird(player) dodges the rocks and if the bird is hit by the rocks it dies. But I can't figure out how to make the game know if the duck got hit by the rock.

Here is my code:

```
import os, sys
import random
import time



img_path = os.path.join('C:\Python27', 'player.png')
img_path2 = os.path.join('C:\Python27', 'rock.png')


class Bird(object):  
    def __init__(self):

        self.image = pygame.image.load(img_path)



        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0


    def handle_keys(self):

        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 2
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]: 
            self.y += dist 
        elif key[pygame.K_UP]: 
            self.y -= dist 
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]: 
            self.x += dist
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]: 
            self.x -= dist 




    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))

   def bird_health(self):
        health = 1
        if health ==0:
            sys.exit()


    def background(self, surface):
        bg = os.path.join('C:\Python27', 'bg.png')
        self.image2 = pygame.image.load(bg)
        surface.blit(self.image2, (0,0))


class Rock(object): 
    def __init__(self, x=640, y=0,):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(img_path2)


        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        dist = 10
        self.dist = dist
    def rock(self):
        dist = 10
        self.x -=dist




    def rock_draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))






pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 200))

bird = Bird() # create an instance
rock = Rock()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


running = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit() # quit the screen
            running = False

        if rock.x < 0:
            y = random.randint(10, 190)
            rock = Rock(640, y)

    bird.handle_keys()    
    rock.rock()
    screen.fill((255,255,255)) 
    bird.background(screen)
    bird.draw(screen)
    rock.rock_draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update() 

    clock.tick(40)
```

For now I just want it to exit if the bird's health = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a program where I detect if the ball hits the paddle in, hope it helps. all the way at the bottom (in a seperate code box thing) is just the code where i detect if they collide.

```
import pygame

# Constants
WIDTH = 700
HEIGHT = 500
SCREEN_AREA = pygame.Rect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

# Initialization
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([WIDTH, HEIGHT])
pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)
pygame.display.set_caption("Breakout Recreation WIP")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Variables
paddle = pygame.Rect(350, 480, 50, 10)
ball = pygame.Rect(10, 250, 15, 15)
paddle_movement_x = 0
ball_direction = (1, 1)
balls = 3
done = False

while not done and balls > 0:

    # Process events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            paddle_movement_x = -2
        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            paddle_movement_x = 2
        else:
            paddle_movement_x = 0

    # Move paddle
    paddle.move_ip(paddle_movement_x, 0)
    paddle.clamp_ip(SCREEN_AREA)

    # Move ball
    ball.move_ip(*ball_direction)
    if ball.right > WIDTH or ball.left < 0:
        ball_direction = -ball_direction[0], ball_direction[1]
    elif ball.top < 0 or paddle.colliderect(ball):
        ball_direction = ball_direction[0], -ball_direction[1]
    elif ball.bottom > HEIGHT:
        balls = balls - 1
        ball_direction = (1, 1)
        ball = pygame.Rect(10, 250, 15, 15)

    ball.clamp_ip(SCREEN_AREA)

    # Redraw screen
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, paddle)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, ball)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(100)

pygame.quit()
```

here is the code where i basically change the ball's direction:

```
    # Move ball
    ball.move_ip(*ball_direction)
    if ball.right > WIDTH or ball.left < 0:
        ball_direction = -ball_direction[0], ball_direction[1]
    elif ball.top < 0 or paddle.colliderect(ball):
        ball_direction = ball_direction[0], -ball_direction[1]
    elif ball.bottom > HEIGHT:
        balls = balls - 1
        ball_direction = (1, 1)
        ball = pygame.Rect(10, 250, 15, 15)
```

Answer (score 4):

I haven't done pygame in a while, but reference this: 
http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollideany

Pygame has a built in collide function, spritecollideany()

or you can use this:

```
def checkCollision(bird, rock):
    if bird.x == rock.x and bird.y == rock.y:
        sys.exit()
```

and in the bird and rock classes, make sure the x and y are accessible. This will only work if the bird's  corner is equal to the rock's corner, but you can add clauses to check. For example:

```
if bird.x == rock.x and bird.y == rock.y or bird.x == rock.x + rock.length and...
```

This will be expanded upon based on where the bird is centered.

Comment: the spritecollideany would work but i think i have to create rects whats the esiest way to do that

Comment: Sorry, it has been forever since I have used pygame. This reference might help: 
http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html

What you need to do is give it an attribute; maybe load the image onto the rect?
I don't have pygame installed so I can't try and check--sorry

Comment: Just an FYI... you forgot to declare 
`import pygame`

Comment: No, I just copied and pasted it and I must have left that out